# How to add new class created in models.py to admin.py (django)

Tags: python, django, class

Any suggestion on this please?

Initially I had class  `Customer():` in `models.py`

This is how the code in `admin.py` looked

```
from django.contrib import admin
from booknowapp.models import Customer

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Customer)
```

Now that I have added two new classes to models how do I register in admin for other new    two classes to appear in the app? I am not sure of the syntax to be used.

Comment: You can call `admin.site.register` once with each class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your added two new classes of models are `ModelClass1` and `ModelClass2` then you can register multiple models in admin.py like :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from booknowapp.models import Customer, ModelClass1, ModelClass2

myModels = [Customer, ModelClass1, ModelClass2]  # iterable list
admin.site.register(myModels)
```

**OR**

You can repeat `admin.site.register` for other two new classes just like your `Customer` .

Comment: Thank you very much Priyank. I had passed Customer, ModelClass1, ModelsClass2 admin.site.register (Customer, ModelClass1, ModelsClass2) I was getting an error. Thank you tons :)

Answer (score 0):

If you extend the syntax that you have already used, it would simply be:

```
from django.contrib import admin
# wrap the line if it's too long
from booknowapp.models import (
    Customer,
    SecondModel,
    ThirdModel
)

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Customer)
admin.site.register(SecondModel)
admin.site.register(ThirdModel)
```

However, this will only give you the default admin model list views - which you will probably want to extend.

```
class CustomerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """Specialised admin view for the Customer model."""
    # set the fields to display 
    list_display = ('name', 'address', 'registered')

# register your Customer model, using the CustomerAdmin view
admin.site.register(Customer, CustomerAdmin)
```

The ModelAdmin has lots more functionality that you can leverage - search fields, filtering, custom fields, custom actions ('Activate customer'), which you can read about here - http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter06.html#custom-modeladmin-classes

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and the link Hugo. It is helpful.